# row number over partition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

cant seem to get row number right, I can get it to count when the template is the same but cant get to keep counting if the template changes

```
create table #temp
(
question varchar(max)
,rvdt datetime
,name varchar(20)
,cdt datetime
,template varchar(max)
)

insert into #temp
(question ,rvdt ,name ,cdt ,template)
values
('question 1', '11/11/2014 10:56:27 PM', 'Joe', '10/11/2014 11:56:27 PM', 'Tempalte 1'),
('question 2', '11/11/2014 10:56:27 PM', 'Joe', '10/11/2014 11:56:27 PM', 'Tempalte 1'),
('question 3', '11/11/2014 10:56:27 PM', 'Joe', '10/11/2014 11:56:27 PM', 'Tempalte 1'),
('question 11', '11/12/2014 10:56:27 PM', 'Joe', '10/12/2014 11:56:27 PM', 'Tempalte 2'),
('question 22', '11/12/2014 10:56:27 PM', 'Joe', '10/12/2014 11:56:27 PM', 'Tempalte 2'),
('question 32', '11/12/2014 10:56:27 PM', 'Joe', '10/12/2014 11:56:27 PM', 'Tempalte 2'),
('question 1', '11/13/2014 10:56:27 PM', 'Joe', '10/13/2014 11:56:27 PM', 'Tempalte 1'),
('question 2', '11/13/2014 10:56:27 PM', 'Joe', '10/13/2014 11:56:27 PM', 'Tempalte 1'),
('question 3', '11/13/2014 10:56:27 PM', 'Joe', '10/13/2014 11:56:27 PM', 'Tempalte 1'),
('question 11', '11/14/2014 10:56:27 PM', 'Mike', '10/14/2014 11:56:27 PM', 'Tempalte 2'),
('question 22', '11/14/2014 10:56:27 PM', 'Mike', '10/14/2014 11:56:27 PM', 'Tempalte 2'),
('question 33', '11/14/2014 10:56:27 PM', 'Mike', '10/14/2014 11:56:27 PM', 'Tempalte 2')

Select 
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name, rvdt order by rvdt )'rv#'
,rvdt
,cdt
,name
,template   
from 
#temp
order by rvdt
drop table #temp
```

i have tried different combinations with whats in the partitin but i cant seem to get the right one

[image]

Comment: Kris is correct, if you make all of Joe's rvdt's the same, it counts without regard to the Template.

Comment: You are partitioning by Name, which in your example data is changing at the same time as the Template column.

Comment: Why don't you just add an Auto incrementing int on the table? Also NVARCHAR(Max) might be overkill for that first column.

Comment: @looksileanevo, dense_rank from below answer should work for you, unless you think it needs to count when template changes instead of when date changes...then it will be like gaps and islands problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Dense_Rank()` `Ranking Function`

```
SELECT Dense_rank()OVER (partition BY name ORDER BY cdt) Rn,
       rvdt,
       cdt,
       name,
       template
FROM   #temp
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Rn  rvdt                    cdt                     name    template
--  ----------------------- ----------------------- ----    ----------
1   2014-11-11 22:56:27.000 2014-10-11 23:56:27.000 Joe     Tempalte 1
1   2014-11-11 22:56:27.000 2014-10-11 23:56:27.000 Joe     Tempalte 1
1   2014-11-11 22:56:27.000 2014-10-11 23:56:27.000 Joe     Tempalte 1
2   2014-11-12 22:56:27.000 2014-10-12 23:56:27.000 Joe     Tempalte 2
2   2014-11-12 22:56:27.000 2014-10-12 23:56:27.000 Joe     Tempalte 2
2   2014-11-12 22:56:27.000 2014-10-12 23:56:27.000 Joe     Tempalte 2
3   2014-11-13 22:56:27.000 2014-10-13 23:56:27.000 Joe     Tempalte 1
3   2014-11-13 22:56:27.000 2014-10-13 23:56:27.000 Joe     Tempalte 1
3   2014-11-13 22:56:27.000 2014-10-13 23:56:27.000 Joe     Tempalte 1
1   2014-11-14 22:56:27.000 2014-10-14 23:56:27.000 Mike    Tempalte 2
1   2014-11-14 22:56:27.000 2014-10-14 23:56:27.000 Mike    Tempalte 2
1   2014-11-14 22:56:27.000 2014-10-14 23:56:27.000 Mike    Tempalte 2
```

Comment: I don't know why this got down voted.  That should work.

Comment: Thank you!, didnt even think of other ranking/numbering functions